# Assigning FileUpload value to a variable in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, file-upload

Is it possible to assign image uploaded using fileupload assigned to a variable? If yes then how can it be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you want to do??? assing the name of the file to a variable??? or save the file???

Request.Files is an array with all files uploaded. so you can do something like this:

```js
//the filename
var fn = Request.Files[0].FileName;

//or save the file to disk
Request.Files[0].SaveAs('c:\somePath');
```